# Plone 6 Volto generate app - Cannot find module 'is-ci'

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, plone, yeoman

This question is related to Plone 6, specifically when attempting to create a new Volto app.

Following [this documentation](https://github.com/plone/volto/tree/master/packages/generator-volto) I am attempting to generate a new Volto project using Yeoman.

I have the prerequisites installed. I've included some versions of the more front end related requirements below:

```
root@ps01:/opt/plone_test/myvoltoapp# nvm version
v16.18.1
root@ps01:/opt/plone_test/myvoltoapp# npm -v
8.19.2
root@ps01:/opt/plone_test/myvoltoapp# node -v
v16.18.1
root@ps01:/opt/plone_test/myvoltoapp# yo --version
4.3.1
root@ps01:/opt/plone_test/myvoltoapp# yarn -v
1.22.19
```

When attempting to run `yo @plone/volto` I receive the following error:

```
root@ps01:/opt/plone_test/myvoltoapp# yo @plone/volto
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'is-ci'
Require stack:
- /root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.1/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/update-notifier/index.js
- /root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.1/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:833:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1057:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at lazy (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.1/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/import-lazy/index.js:2:51)
    at /root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.1/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/import-lazy/index.js:10:11
    at new UpdateNotifier (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.1/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/update-notifier/index.js:46:4)
    at module.exports (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.1/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/update-notifier/index.js:183:25)
    at updateCheck (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.1/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js:54:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.1/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js:187:1) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.1/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/update-notifier/index.js',
    '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.1/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js'
  ]
}
```

I can confirm I do have is-ci installed (although globally) and root has access to the folder.

```
root@ps01:/opt/plone_test/myvoltoapp# ls -lha /root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.1/lib/node_modules
total 28K
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4.0K Nov 10 11:04 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 1001 1001 4.0K Nov  4 11:33 ..
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4.0K Nov  4 11:33 corepack
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Nov  9 20:07 is-ci
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4.0K Nov  4 11:33 npm
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Nov 10 11:04 @plone
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4.0K Nov 10 11:04 yo
```

I'm not really sure where to go from here, if anyone has any information or can point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please ask for Plone help in our forum https://community.plone.org